# I can't compile a solution due to "Error LNK2028: unresolved token..."

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unresolved-external

I have a dll programmed in C++, and a exe programmed in Visual C++.

I have the functions in dll declared as:

```
string __declspec( dllexport ) ConfigureHAT(T_STRING pathFile);
```

And in the exe project I include all the headers files and the dll file.

I call the function in dll:

```
string ret = ConfigureHAT("file.txt");
```

And when the executable project is compiled, it fails with the next errors:

> 1>HATdllTester.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000317) "class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > __cdecl ConfigureHAT(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator >)"
>   (?ConfigureHAT@@$$FYA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@Z)
>   referenced in function "private: void __clrcall
>   HATdllTester::mainWindow::buttonConfigure_Click(class System::Object
>   ^,class System::EventArgs ^)"
>   (?buttonConfigure_Click@mainWindow@HATdllTester@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
>
> 1>AssemblyInfo.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000316) "class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > __cdecl ConfigureHAT(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator >)"
>   (?ConfigureHAT@@$$FYA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@Z)
>   referenced in function "private: void __clrcall
>   HATdllTester::mainWindow::buttonConfigure_Click(class System::Object
>   ^,class System::EventArgs ^)"
>   (?buttonConfigure_Click@mainWindow@HATdllTester@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
>
> 1>AssemblyInfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > __cdecl ConfigureHAT(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator >)"
>   (?ConfigureHAT@@$$FYA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@Z)
>   referenced in function "private: void __clrcall
>   HATdllTester::mainWindow::buttonConfigure_Click(class System::Object
>   ^,class System::EventArgs ^)"
>   (?buttonConfigure_Click@mainWindow@HATdllTester@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
>
> 1>HATdllTester.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > __cdecl ConfigureHAT(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator >)"
>   (?ConfigureHAT@@$$FYA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@Z)

Can anybody help me?
I read a lot of similar messages with the same error, but no one solves my problem.

Thanks.

## **EDIT**

Finally, I solve the problem including the .lib file generated in the dll project into Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

Comment: does VC++ allows the use of C++ symbols in dll ? AFAIK, you have to export the symbol in C for it to work (i.e. `extern "C" { /* declaration */ }`)

Comment: Are you linking with the `.lib` generated alongside the `.dll`? (p.s: returning a `std::string` across a DLL boundary is a very bad idea.)

Comment: Yes, I'm linking with the .lib. Why is a very bad idea returning a std:string? I didn't know it.

Comment: That function needs to be declared __declspec(dllimport) in your project.  Check the macro soup in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4721458/17034).

Comment: @Geoffroy Thank You, You saved my project with the `extern` hint

Comment: @Geoffroy it absolutely does, please don't spread myths.

Comment: @n.m. that was a simple question, and FYI C++ didn't have any draft for a standard ABI, so although it may work for VC++ (which is why I asked for additional information), it is not portable to do so.

Comment: @Geoffroy DLLs are specific to Windows. The C++ standard doesn't talk about user-built libraries at all. Neither does the C standard. We are talking about building DLLs with MSVC, not about a portable way to create libraries, which does not exist.

Comment: @n.m. I spoke about ABI, and this is all about ABI in fact. Anyway, this was just a question, and in no case a will to spread a myth or anything

Comment: @Geoffroy OK so here's the answer: if such restriction existed, it would make it impossible to create a library that exposes a C++ interface (classes, member functions, overloads), thereby making C++ rather unusable as a development language on the Windows platform. Since libraries with C++ interfaces evidently exist, and C++ thrives, such restriction cannot possibly be in place.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try changing Visual Studio project configuration. Under General > Common Language Runtime Support set `/clr` instead of `/clr:pure`.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me when I changed `CLR` MyProjectCLR.vcxproj project file and added a link to  `C` MyProjectC.vcxproj project

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include=".\MyProjectC.csproj">
        <Project>{f6ead438-e6cf-4df6-b2f4-d33d533c5343}</Project>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```