# C++ WindowsApp LNK2028Error

Tags: c++, windows, c++-cli

When I compile the following code in Visual Studio 2019 I receive the following error code: [code of the error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6xO0.png). It seems to be a [LNK2028](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f01a0bea-7441-4fab-949c-23a68e775c31/lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-when-calling-external-c-function?forum=vclanguage) error but I do not understand what is happening. Can someone explain why I receive this error?

Here is my code:

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND p = FindWindowEx(hwnd, NULL, _T("SHELLDLL_DefView"), false);
    HWND* ret = (HWND*)lParam;
    if (p) {
        // Gets the WorkerW Window after the current one.
        *ret = FindWindowEx(NULL, hwnd, _T("WorkerW"), NULL);
    }
    return true;
}

HWND get_wallpaper_window()
{
    // Fetch the Progman window
    HWND progman = FindWindow(_T("ProgMan"), NULL);
    // Send 0x052C to Progman. This message directs Progman to spawn a
    // WorkerW behind the desktop icons. If it is already there, nothing
    // happens.
    SendMessageTimeout(progman, 0x052C, 0, 0, SMTO_NORMAL, 1000, NULL);
    // We enumerate all Windows, until we find one, that has the SHELLDLL_DefView
    // as a child.
    // If we found that window, we take its next sibling and assign it to workerw.
    HWND wallpaper_hwnd = NULL;
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)&wallpaper_hwnd);
    // Return the handle you're looking for.
    return wallpaper_hwnd;
}
[STAThread]


void main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles;
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    DEM0::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(% form);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sarsatra. How do you build this project? What tools / commands etc?

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the errors as _text_, not an image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022481/i-cant-compile-a-solution-due-to-error-lnk2028-unresolved-token Maybe similar to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022481/i-cant-compile-a-solution-due-to-error-lnk2028-unresolved-token) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f01a0bea-7441-4fab-949c-23a68e775c31/lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-when-calling-external-c-function?forum=vclanguage) post it seems like the issue is due to a linker error which is caused by (I believe 8 function calls) that are depending on libraries implemented by the `User32.dll` located in `C:\windows\system32` [more info about this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/729a1e6b-df77-49f4-8d71-b0da95585220/what-is-causing-these-unresolved-externals-message?forum=vcgeneral).

In this current project it seems like you are missing to include additional dependencies. You can include those by going to **Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.** Here you can choose to include the `User32.dll` file or choose the `"Inherit from parent or project defaults"` option. I believe this will solve your linker errors.