# Macro for dllexport/dllimport switch

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

```
#if COMPILING_DLL
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

How / where do I define `COMPILING_DLL` ?

Seen here: 
[what does __declspec(dllimport) really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863193/what-does-declspecdllimport-really-mean)

Sounds like I can't use load-time dynamic linking at all if I can't use the same header?

[image]

Comment: Seems that you have some strange mistake somewhere that is not mentioned here. Rest assured, it should work, DLLs are very useful.

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/importing-into-an-application-using-declspec-dllimport?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Best place to define `COMPILING_DLL=1` is command line of compiler. If you use Visual Studio IDE then it is in Project properties ... C/C++ ... Preprocessor ...  Preprocessor Definitions.

`__declspec(dllimport)` is Microsoft specific extension to C++. Microsoft has excellent online documentation.

Comment: I added COMPILING_DLL to the preprocessor definitions, but it's still complaining "error C2491: 'test2' : definition of dllimport function not allowed". Which makes no sense, because Visual Studio even grays out the correct one now. I added a screenshot to illustrate this.

Comment: You should add that COMPILING_DLL to preprocessor definitions of your DLL project. If you have that header included in precompiled header of that project, make sure you rebuild it.

Answer (score 22):

**One another option:**

Use the **default** defined macro **local** to the project.

You can see the default defined macros local to the project in the below location:

**Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definition.**

**Example:**

Suppose your Project Name is: **MyDLL**

Default Macro Local to that project: **MYDLL_EXPORTS**

```
 #ifdef  MYDLL_EXPORTS 
    /*Enabled as "export" while compiling the dll project*/
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)  
 #else
    /*Enabled as "import" in the Client side for using already created dll file*/
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllimport)  
 #endif
```

Comment: It's a shame that the most useful code to copy in this question isn't in the accepted answer. At least you have it here for us :)

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck that code is already in question.

Comment: Once I have created a dll, still when using it in another project, MYDLL_EXPORTS remains set while it should be unset here. Could somebody please let me know why this is happening??

Answer (score 2):

In the DLL project, you add a `#define` (either in a header file or in the project properties) for `COMPILING_DLL`. As this will not be set for any other project (especially if you name it something better than `COMPILING_DLL`) then the `#if` directive will work properly.

Answer (score 2):

You (actually Visual Studio in ideal cases) defines the `COMPILING_DLL` as an argument to the compiler when you build the DLL. So, it will default to `__declspec(dllexport)`. On the other end, when you USE the DLL's header file, you don't define this, so `DLLEXPORT` will be evaluated by default to `__declspec(dllimport)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use CMake to generate your build configuration, you should be able to use
the macro `<projectname>_EXPORTS` the way you want to use `COMPILING_DLL`, where `projectname` was defined with the CMake command `project(projectname)`:

> A preprocessor macro, `<target_name>_EXPORTS` is defined when a shared library compilation is detected.

[source](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/FindCUDA.html)

I tested and it works on Windows using the Ninja generator with compiler MSVC from Visual Studio 2015 Express.

Related: [CMake adds -Dlibname_EXPORTS compile definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429732/cmake-adds-dlibname-exports-compile-definition)

Answer (score 1):

You can't define function body that way in the header file. It is [prohibited by __declspec(dllimport)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62688esh%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). This specifier can only be specified on function declaration, not definition.

You have to move the function body to a source file.

in header file:

```
extern DLLEXPORT void test2();
```

In .cpp file:

```
void test2()
{
   // ...
}
```

As folks said, don't forget to add COMPILING_DLL to the project preprocessor definitions.

Comment: The source of compiler error you have mentioned ("error C2491: 'test2' : definition of dllimport function not allowed") was this. But it seems it can be solved by explicitly using `#define COMPILING_DLL` in code instead of adding it to: Project>properties>C/C++>Preprocessor>Preprocessor Definitions

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the real problem is the preprocessor directive.
You should use `#ifdef` and not `#if` to test if the variable is really defined (and we don't care about the defined value or if there is any).

NOTE: I know this thread is 1-year old but it still may be useful for somebody who have this problem in the future.

Comment: You can use `#if` so long as it is accomponied by `defined` or `!defined`, ie `#if defined SOMETHING || !defined SOMETHING_ELSE`