# CMake adds -Dlibname_EXPORTS compile definition

Tags: cmake

CMake adds the following compile definition to all source code files automatically when simply compiling a target:

```
-Dlibname_EXPORTS
```

Why is this done and how can I disable it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

cmake add `<libname>_EXPORTS` macros only for shared libraries. It's useful when exporting API's in Windows DLL.

```
#if defined(_WINDOWS) && defined(testlib_EXPORTS)
#   define API_DLL extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API_DLL
#endif

API_DLL void foo();
```

It could be disabled by setting the `DEFINE_SYMBOL` property of target to empty.

```
# disable the <libname>_EXPORTS
set_target_properties(sharedlib
  PROPERTIES
  DEFINE_SYMBOL ""
  )
```

**Reference**

- http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/DEFINE_SYMBOL.html

Comment: How can I disable this behaviour?