# Share header files within two Visual Studio 2010 C++ projects ( DLL and a Win32 project)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, stdafx.h

I have two VS10 projects, one is a (not MFC) DLL. I want to use in the DLL project a `struct` defined in one header file of the other project. The projects use the precompiled headers and all the includes are made under `stdafx.h`.

***Project One***

```
struct example
{
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

***DLL Project***

```
#include "stdafx.h"


extern "C"
{

    __declspec(dllexport) int ex(struct example *p)
    {
        int c = p->a;

        return 1;
    }


}
```

`struct example` must be visible from the DLL project. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You need to use a macro that changes `__declspec(dllexport)` to `__declspec(dllimport)` when using the dll. There should be 1000s of examples if you search.

Comment: could you be more exhaustive?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980649/macro-for-dllexport-dllimport-switch

Comment: the project that contains the definition of the struct is not a DLL project how can i export from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved at compile time by putting the Struct in a separate header file and including it in both projects.