# Dodging the inaccuracy of a floating point number

Tags: c, floating-point, numbers, precision

I totally understand the problems associated with floating points, but I have seen a very interesting behavior that I can't explain.

```
float x = 1028.25478;
long int y = 102825478;
float z = y/(float)100000.0;
printf("x = %f ", x);
printf("z = %f",z);
```

The output is:

> x = 1028.254761 z = 1028.254780

Now if floating numbers failed to represent that specific random value (1028.25478) when I assigned that to variable x. Why isn't it the same in case of variable z?

P.S. I'm using pellesC IDE to test the code (C11 compiler).

Comment: Your code [prints the same thing for me](https://ideone.com/9zyYyF).

Comment: Try printing a few more decimals, with e.g. `"%.10f"`.

Comment: This isn't the duplicate. I think there are several actual duplicates, but they are hard to find. Basically, the compiler performs math as `double` in the second case.

Comment: Reopened. This is a type conversion issues, not a floating point issue per se.

Comment: I had a similar question not too long ago (albeit in a different context). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47066540/7159784) that I got. Also read the comments on the question for a deeper understanding.

Comment: The question seems to presuppose some false premises.  The biggest is that the float value obtained by converting the `long int` 102825478 to type `float` is precisely 100000 times larger than the `float` constant 1028.25478.  Even if that were true, the assumption that floating-point division of the former by 100000 would then yield exactly the latter is also unsafe.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the case is that why does it *print `1028.25478`* when `float = 1028.25478;` clearly truncates to `1028.254761`.

Comment: Priniting using %.10f : x = 1028.2547607422 z = 1028.2547800000

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, because `printf()` rounds the value.

Comment: How is `1028.254761` rounded to `1028.25478`, that is not the nearest float value.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the next `float` from `1028.2547607421875` is `1028.25` **`50048828125`**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am pretty sure that what happens here is that the latter floating point variable is elided and instead kept in a double-precision register; and then passed as is as an argument to `printf`. Then the compiler will believe that it is safe to pass this number at double precision after default argument promotions.

I managed to produce a *similar* result using GCC 7.2.0, with these switches:

```
-Wall -Werror -ffast-math -m32 -funsafe-math-optimizations -fexcess-precision=fast -O3
```

The output is

```
x = 1028.254761 z = 1028.254800
```

The number is slightly different there^.

The [description for `-fexcess-precision=fast`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html) says:

> `-fexcess-precision=style`
>
> This option allows further control over excess precision on
>              machines where floating-point operations occur in a format with
>              more precision or range than the IEEE standard and interchange
>              floating-point types.  By default, `-fexcess-precision=fast` is in
>              effect; this means that operations may be carried out in a wider
>              precision than the types specified in the source if that would
>              result in faster code, and it is unpredictable when rounding to
>              the types specified in the source code takes place.  When
>              compiling C, if `-fexcess-precision=standard` is specified then
>              excess precision follows the rules specified in ISO C99; in
>              particular, both casts and assignments cause values to be rounded
>              to their semantic types (whereas `-ffloat-store` only affects
>              assignments). This option [`-fexcess-precision=standard`] is enabled by default for C if a
>              strict conformance option such as `-std=c99` is used.  `-ffast-math`
>              enables `-fexcess-precision=fast` by default regardless of whether
>              a strict conformance option is used.

This behaviour isn't C11-compliant

Comment: That makes a lot of sense to me, but I'm sure that it is C11.

Comment: Also, the CCFlags are: -std:C11 -Tx86-coff -Ot -Ob1 -fp:precise -W1 -Gd

Comment: yeah, so, it must be a case of bad compiler. Can you get the *assembler output* from Pelle's?

Answer (score 2):

Restricting this to IEEE754 strict floating point, the answers *should* be the same.

`1028.25478` is actually `1028.2547607421875`. That accounts for `x`.

In the evaluation of `y / (float)100000.0;`, `y` is converted to a `float`, by C's rules of argument promotion. The closest `float` to `102825478` is `102825480`. IEEE754 requires the returning of the the best result of a division, which should be `1028.2547607421875` (the value of `z`): the closest number to `1028.25480`.

So my answer is at odds with your observed behaviour. I put that down to your compiler not implementing floating point strictly; or perhaps not implementing IEEE754.

Comment: And of course, C does not require implementations to adhere strictly or even at all to IEEE-754. In practice, though, substantially all implementations for modern, general-purpose platforms in fact do use IEEE-754 formats and at least approximate IEEE-754 semantics.  Many *do not* adhere strictly to IEEE-754, at least by default.

Answer (score 2):

Code acts as if `z` was a `double` and `y/(float)100000.0` is `y/100000.0`.

```
float x = 1028.25478;
long int y = 102825478;
double z = y/100000.0;

// output
x = 1028.254761 z = 1028.254780
```

---

An important consideration is `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`. This allows select floating point code to evaluate at higher precision.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
printf("FLT_EVAL_METHOD %d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
```

> Except for **assignment** and cast ..., the values yielded by operators with floating operands and values subject to the usual arithmetic conversions and of floating constants are evaluated to a format whose range and precision may be greater than required by the type. The use of evaluation formats is characterized by the implementation-defined value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.

`-1` indeterminable;
`0` evaluate all operations and constants just to the range and precision of the
type;
`1` evaluate ... type `float` and `double` to the
range and precision of the `double` type, evaluate `long double`
... to the range and precision of the `long double`
type;
`2` evaluate all ... to the range and precision of the
`long double` type.

Yet this does **not** apply as `z` with `float z = y/(float)100000.0;` should lose all higher precision on the assignment.

---

I agree with [@Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47927974/2410359) that code is using a speed optimization that has less adherence to the expected rules of floating point math.