# Entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library - c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, entry-point, cpprest-sdk

I created a DLL project in visual c++, and I wanted to use the `cpprestsdk/casablanca`.

Then I created a `RestWrapper.h` header file:

```
#pragma once

namespace mycpprest
{
    class RestWrapper
    {
    public:
        static __declspec(dllexport) void TestApi();
    };
}
```

And `RestWrapper.cpp` source file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "RestWrapper.h"

#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
#include <cpprest/json.h>

using namespace utility;
using namespace web;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;
using namespace concurrency::streams;

namespace mycpprest
{
    void RestWrapper::TestApi()
    {
        auto fileStream = std::make_shared<ostream>();

        // Open stream to output file.
        pplx::task<void> requestTask = fstream::open_ostream(U("results.html")).then([=](ostream outFile)
        {
            *fileStream = outFile;

            // Create http_client to send the request.
            http_client client(U("http://13.231.231.252:3000/api/individual_employment_setting/detail/172"));

            // Build request URI and start the request.
            //uri_builder builder(U("/search"));
            //builder.append_query(U("q"), U("cpprestsdk github"));
            return client.request(methods::GET);
        })

        // Handle response headers arriving.
        .then([=](http_response response)
        {
            printf("Received response status code:%u\n", response.status_code());

            // Write response body into the file.
            // return response.body().read_to_end(fileStream->streambuf());
            stringstreambuf buffer;
            response.body().read_to_end(buffer).get();

            //show content in console
            printf("Response body: \n %s", buffer.collection().c_str());

            //parse content into a JSON object:
            //json::value jsonvalue = json::value::parse(buffer.collection());

            return  fileStream->print(buffer.collection()); //write to file anyway
        })

        // Close the file stream.
        .then([=](size_t)
        {
            return fileStream->close();
        });

        // Wait for all the outstanding I/O to complete and handle any exceptions
        try
        {
            requestTask.wait();
        }
        catch (const std::exception &e)
        {
            printf("Error exception:%s\n", e.what());
        }
    }
}
```

When I build it, It success built.

Then I created `Windows Console Application` in visual c++ to test the DLL project that I created.

I copy the `MyCpprestDll.dll, MyCpprestDll.lib and RestWrapper.h` from `MycppestDll project` into `DllTest project`.

Then in DllTest project `properties`, in the `Linker->input->Additional Dependencies`: I added `MyCpprestDll.lib`

And here the code of `DllTest.cpp:`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "RestWrapper.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace mycpprest;

int main()
{
    RestWrapper::TestApi();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

It has no compile error, but when running the error says:

> ```
> The procedure entry point ?TestApi@RestWrapper@mycpprest@@SAXXZ could not be located in the dynamic link library
> ```

[image]

I tried to search about the related issues but I don't know how to or what to set to my entry point in my dll project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dllexport` when building your DLL, but `dllimport` when you are including it into another project

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980649/macro-for-dllexport-dllimport-switch/14980783) shows you have to use some macros and pre-processor definitions to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In your RestWrapper.h header file do something as shown below. 
Note that you must use __declspec(dllimport) for the importing executable to access the DLL's public data symbols and objects. 
Also, make sure you define the macro RestWrapper_EXPORTS in C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions in your DLL project properties.

```
#ifdef RestWrapper_EXPORTS
#define RestWrapper_APIS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define RestWrapper_APIS __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace mycpprest
{
 // This class is exported from the RestWrapper.dll
 class RestWrapper 
 {
   public:
    static RestWrapper_APIS void TestApi();     
 };
}
```

Rebuild your DLL project. No changes needed in your DllTest project, just compile your DllTest project using the updated RestWrapper.h and RestWrapper.lib file.