# Static member variable not global between executable and dll

Tags: c++, linker

My knowledge is a bit fuzzy in terms of how linking a DLL works but I'm observing a change to a static member variable in an executable that doesn't change the same static member variable in a DLL.  Here's the scenario I have:

main.cpp is statically linked to mylib.lib.  Within mylib.lib, I have the following class:

```
// foo.h
class Foo
{
public:
    static int m_global;
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
};
```

and

```
// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"

int Foo::m_global = 5;
```

I also have a DLL that links to mylib.lib with the following:

```
//testdll.h
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)

void MATHLIBRARY_API printFoo();
```

and

```
// testdll.cpp
#include "testdll.h"
#include <iostream>

void printFoo() {
    std::cout << Foo::m_global << std::endl;
}
```

Finally, in main.cpp of my executable

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "testdll.h"
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << Foo::m_global << std::endl;
    Foo::m_global = 7;

    std::cout << Foo::m_global << std::endl;
    printMutiply();

    return 0;
}
```

My expected output is 5, 7, 7.  However, I'm seeing 5, 7, 5 which is telling me that the static member variable change isn't being seen by the DLL.  Why is this so?  And how can I make the DLL see changes in the static member variable made in the executable??

Comment: If you compile the DLL, the `class foo` has to be attributed with `__declspec(dllexport)`. If you compile executable, the (same) `class foo` has to be attributed `__declspec(dllimport)`. This is often done (e.g. by us) using some macro trickery. I found a concerning SO Q/A: [SO: Macro for dllexport/dllimport switch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14980649/7478597) which might be of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Believe it or not, but your application violates One Definition Rule, and as such, triggers Undefined Behavior. Your `program` (as it is called in C++ standard) ends up having double definition of `Foo::m_global` - one in the loadable library, and another one inside `main`. As an observable effect of this undefined behavior, Microsoft dynamic loader creates two symbols, one from loadable object, another from main.

In Linux word, `ld` (linux loader) would actually conflate those symbols into one (which would, in turn, trigger double destruction for non-trivial objects).

Bottom line - do not share definitions of global symbols between loadable libraries and executable. This goes for both functions and variables, but sharing functions usually does not have a visible side-effect, although technically is undefined behavior as well.

Comment: _do not share global symbols between loadable libraries and executable._ I don't get it. How will you ever call any library function from outside? Do you consider "global" != "extern"?

Comment: @Scheff by sharing I meant sharing **definition**. My wording is not perfect, I will edit.

Comment: I only see one definition of `Foo::m_global` (the `int Foo::m_global = 5;` in `foo.cpp`). Where is the second one?

Comment: @rubenvb in the question description OP says the dll and main executable link to the same lib.

Comment: @SergeyA Right, that gives the program (the linked binary of main.cpp and foo.cpp and testdll.cpp) exactly one definition of `Foo::m_global`.

Comment: @rubenvb, no. It gives program exactly two definitions of it. Both loadable library and main executable have a definition of `Foo::m_global`, and when loadable is loaded into executable, you end up with two.

Comment: @SergeyA, ah, there's static linking involved. That's highly confusing and wrong indeed. You should add to your answer a proper solution instead of only a description of the problem.

Comment: @rubenvb and happens all the time! It is actually quite hard to avoid it :) when using common libraries. I do not know proper solution, because OP didn't provide reasoning for statically linking. I am pretty sure the toy example is not the real code.

Comment: @sergeyA you're correct, the example here is representative of an issue I'm seeing in a larger code base

Comment: @SergeyA given freedom of design, how would you approach resolving this issue??

Comment: Not link anything statically, most likely. @Joe

Comment: I see - sorry that it's not obvious for me.  How would you go about sharing the static member with the DLL with it defined in one place? @SergeyA

Comment: @Joe, I am talking in generalities, because I do not have your real case. What I meant was that you do not link libraries static in this scenario at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we handle it in our projects:

```
/* First a general definition which covers differences
 * of Windows and Linux for all of your libraries:
 */
#ifdef _WIN32
/* for Windows, Visual C++ */
#define MY_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define MY_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#else /* _WIN32 */
/* for gcc */
#define MY_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define MY_IMPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#endif /* _WIN32 */
```

This has to be prepared for each of your libraries:

```
/* The API macro to distiguish two cases:
 * 1. DLL/Shared Object
 * 2. usage of DLL/Shared Object
 */
#ifdef BUILD_MY_LIB
#define  MY_LIB_API MY_EXPORT
#else /* BUILD_MY_LIB */
#define MY_LIB_API MY_IMPORT
#endif /* BUILD_MY_LIB */
```

`MY_LIB_API` is then used in any `class` to be exported from MyLib library:

```
class MY_LIB_API Foo {
};
```

The rest is done with compiler arguments:

1. To compile the MyLib DLL or Shared Object, `-DBUILD_MY_LIB` is added to command line arguments of compiler.
2. To use the DLL or Shared Object, no additional setting is necessary.

Actually, our solution considers static libraries also. It defines `MY_LIB_API` to be empty. However, we didn't used it for a long time anymore. Hence, I left this part out. (I must admit I forgot how it works in detail...)