# Porting DLL import from c# to c++

Tags: c#, c++, dll

This is how I use/import the DLL using c#. How do I do it on c++ project?

```
[DllImport(@".\x64\something.dll", EntryPoint = "somthng", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int somthng(string input);
```

Comment: Are you targeting the Windows platform?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Targeting a C# dll in C++? Or just including a C++ library in C++?

Comment: In native `c++` you probably want to have a macro change from `__declspec(dllexport)` when building the dll to `__declspec(dllimport)` when using the dll. Here is a question that should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980649/macro-for-dllexport-dllimport-switch

Comment: Yes @J.R.......

Comment: @FranzHuber23 Use an external DLL in c++ that was also used in c# project

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you do not have the development header and lib files available for the DLL and you need to dynamically load the DLL into your C++ project, then you can do the following.

Define a function pointer (equivalent to your `extern` declaration):

```
typedef int FnSomeFunction(const char* input);
```

Load the library (I'm using `LoadLibraryA` here to load an ansi-named DLL, this depends on your C++ project). The DLL must be in the search path, i.e. in the same path as the executable):

```
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibraryA("something.dll");
```

Check that the module is successfully loaded:

```
if (hModule == nullptr)
    throw std::runtime_error("Lib not loaded");
```

Get the function entry point from the library:

```
FnSomething* fnSomething = (FnSomeFunction*)GetProcAddress(hModule, "somthng");
```

Call the function:

```
(*fnSomething)("some text");
```

Free the library when no longer needed:

```
FreeLibrary(hModule);
```

Comment: Alternatively, just build your C++ project against the appropriate header (.h) and import library (.lib) so that you can just call the function directly. If you can link directly against the import library, it will be much more convenient if there are a lot of functions to import.

Comment: True; my assumption was that these were not available. I'll update the answer to reflect this.