# How to build library function?

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I want to build a small reusable library.
I have 2 projects, project A to build a library function (must dynamic library), and project B to run tests on it.

My problem encountered the following error:
In project B I used the following code:

```
 #include "StdAfx.h"
 #include "C:\......\projectA\Ent extension.h" (same folder with "Ent extension.cpp")
 void Call_plot()
 {
      ...=fent_select(..);
 }
```

however when I build the project I always get an error:

```
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class Ent __cdecl fent_select(wchar_t const ,enum Mode)" (?fent_select@@YAPEAVEnt@@PEB_WW4Mode@Db@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl" Call_plot (?Call_plot@@YAXXZ)
```

How i can fix this problem?

Thanks you!

Comment: @StephenNewell: did I build projectA.lib the wrong way? I simply compile and add projectA.lib to the linker projectB

Comment: You did not give enough information for anyone to provide more help than the duplicate that explains many of the common causes of this linker error.

Comment: Thanks all, turns out I was missing __declspec. now every function works as expected.

Comment: Normally in  native c++ using msvc you need a macro that evaluates to `__declspec(dllexport)` when building the dll and `__declspec(dllimport)` when using the dll. Related:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980649/macro-for-dllexport-dllimport-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980649/macro-for-dllexport-dllimport-switch)

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the object codes from both source code files together (and when you compile source code, it often turns into an object code).  *How* to do this is somewhat dependent on your operating system and compiler.  But, for example using GNU's `gcc` compiler, it would take the following compilation lines.

1. Step 1, compile the base code you want include:

```
gcc -g -o Ent_extension.o Ent_extension.cpp
```

2. Step 2, compile your code that wants to use the extension, telling it where the header file is for the base projectA using `-I` (include path):

```
gcc -I C:\......\projectA\ -g -o project_B.o project_B.cpp
```

But neither of these files is executable yet until you link them together, which takes the last step:

3. Link them together into an executable:

```
gcc -o myprogram project_B.o C:\......\projectA\Ent_extension.o
```

Which will create `myprogram` out of both your code bases.

Note: the even more advanced way is to turn the projectA code into a library and link that in, but that should be a future task.