# Each CTest executable is several MB - how do I make them smaller?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, ctest

I have a bunch of unit tests I want to migrate from Visual Studio's test framework to something more accessible. I started moving some to ctest, where (as I understand) each test needs to compile to a separate executable.

My cmakelists.txt looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(UnitTests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 1)



include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(Test1 Test1.cpp)
add_executable(Test2 Test2.cpp)


add_test(First Test1)
add_test(Second Test2)
```

The problem is that Test1 and Test2 compile to files of 2.7 and 2.6 MB, respectively. This is because each has to have `#include "BigClass.h"`, where `BigClass` is the big, sprawling project I actually want to test.

I have maybe a few dozen tests I want to migrate, so to compile and run all these tests would likely run into hundreds of megabytes of executables, where most of the space is simply repeating all the code from `BigClass`!

I tried to include this class as a library with:

```
add_library(BigClass SHARED ../path/to/BigClass.cpp)
```

and then at the end of the file:

```
target_link_libraries(Test1 PUBLIC BigClass)
```

but this did not affect the space.

I think what I want is a way to dynamically link to `BigClass` (which would be compiled already anyway), so all the tests can share the code. But I'm not sure how to do this and I'm not quite sure how to search for it (searching for dynamically linked `#include` reveals that this is not really possible, for example).

Can anyway help me find either:

1. a cross-platform C++ testing framework that avoids all these problems?
2. a way to compile unit tests in ctest to share a lot of the same code?
3. directions on how to link C++ classes dynamically?

Comment: FYI: [CMake: Step 9: Selecting Static or Shared Libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Selecting%20Static%20or%20Shared%20Libraries.html). However, if you're on Windows you have to care about proper export / import of symbols of your DLL. Otherwise, you will end up in link issues. [SO: Macro for dllexport/dllimport switch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24209060/7478597).

Comment: To define the resp. macro like described in the link, you can use an additional line in CMake. Assuming, you are using `add_library(BigClass BigClass.cc)` then add `set_target_properties(BigClass PROPERTIES DEFINE_SYMBOL BUILD_BIG_CLASS)` and `BUILD_BIG_CLASS` is then you macro to test for whether you have to export or import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. a cross-platform C++ testing framework that avoids all these problems?

Ignoring the fact that code recommendations are off-topic…
We are using [catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2), and I'm quite happy with this.

> 2. a way to compile unit tests in ctest to share a lot of the same code?

Tests are yet other applications. So, the answer to next question should cover this.

> 3. directions on how to link C++ classes dynamically?

I've made an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where I tried to cover the whole story. Be prepared…

---

When code is written to become part of a DLL, it has to export all symbols which shall become visible in other DLLs or the executable. The other DLLs and the executable have to import these symbols in turn. There is a general introduction to this topic provided by Microsoft: [dllexport, dllimport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/dllexport-dllimport?view=msvc-160).

There is a usual macro trickery to ensure that the same headers can be used from inside the DLL (where `dllexport` is needed) and outside of DLL (where `dllimport` is needed).

This is demonstrated in the `BigClass.h`:

```
#ifndef BIG_CLASS_H
#define BIG_CLASS_H

/* A macro trickery to provide export and import prefixes
 * platform dependent for Windows and Linux.
 */
#ifdef _WIN32
// for Windows, Visual C++
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define DLL_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#else // (not) _WIN32
// for gcc
#define DLL_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define DLL_IMPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#endif // _WIN32

/* The macro trickery to define how exported symbols shall
 * be included.
 */
#ifdef BIG_CLASS_STATIC
#define BIG_CLASS_API
#else // (not) BIG_CLASS_STATIC
#ifdef BUILD_BIG_CLASS
#define  BIG_CLASS_API DLL_EXPORT
#else // (not) BUILD_BIG_CLASS
#define BIG_CLASS_API DLL_IMPORT
#endif // BUILD_BIG_CLASS
#endif // BIG_CLASS_STATIC

// the library interface

#include <iostream>

struct BigClass {
  const int id = 0;

  // inline constructors doesn't need an export guard
  BigClass() = default;

  // non-inline constructors need an export guard
  BIG_CLASS_API BigClass(int id);

  // non-inline functins as well
  BIG_CLASS_API void print() const;

  // no export guard for inline member functions
  void printLn() const
  {
    print();
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
};

// functions need to be exported
extern BIG_CLASS_API void print(const BigClass&);

// inline functions don't need to be exported
inline void printLn(const BigClass& big)
{
  big.printLn();
}

#endif // BIG_CLASS_H
```

Thereby, the first macros `DLL_EXPORT` and `DLL_IMPORT` are introduced to hide the different declaration attributes between Windows (Visual Studio) and Linux (g++).

These definitions can be shared over multiple libraries.

The second set of macros is library specific – hence, the prefix `BIG_CLASS_` in all of them.

The `BIG_CLASS_STATIC` is a macro which should be defined as argument for the compiler if (and only if) the library is built as static library. It has to be defined as well if the static library has to be linked to an executable.

The `BUILD_BIG_CLASS` is a macro which should be defined instead as argument for the compiler if (and only if) the library is built and linked as DLL (or shared object in Linux).

Both macros are considered to prepare a third macro `BIG_CLASS_API` which expands to

- nothing for a static library
- `DLL_EXPORT` if the DLL is built
- `DLL_IMPORT` if anything else is built intended to use and link the DLL.

The corresponding `BigClass.cc`:

```
#include "BigClass.h"

BigClass::BigClass(int id): id(id) { }

void BigClass::print() const
{
  std::cout << "BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: " << id << " }";
}

void print(const BigClass& big)
{
  std::cout << "print(): "; big.print();
}
```

There is nothing special about it.

`BigClass.h` and `BigClass.cc` will be used to build the sample `BigClass.dll`.

Additionally, two test applications `Test1` and `Test2` which shall be linked with `BigClass.dll`.

`Test1.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <BigClass.h>

#define TEST(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  std::cout
    << "Test1:\n"
    << "======\n";
  TEST(BigClass big);
  TEST(big.print());
  std::cout << '\n';
  TEST(big.printLn());
  TEST(BigClass big1(1));
  TEST(big1.print());
  std::cout << '\n';
  TEST(big1.printLn());
  std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;
}
```

`Test2.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <BigClass.h>

#define TEST(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  std::cout
    << "Test2:\n"
    << "======\n";
  TEST(BigClass big);
  TEST(print(big));
  std::cout << '\n';
  TEST(printLn(big));
  TEST(BigClass big2(2));
  TEST(print(big2));
  std::cout << '\n';
  TEST(printLn(big2));
  std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;
}
```

Again, there is nothing special about them.

*Disclaimer:* The macro `TEST()` has nothing to do with unit tests. It's just a kind of demo fiddling.

Finally, the `CMakeLists.txt` to put everything together (e.g. in a VS solution `BigClassDLL.sln`):

```
project (BigClassDLL)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
if (MSVC)
  # Unfortunately neither
  # CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
  # nor 
  # CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
  # force the /permissive- option
  # which makes MSVC standard conform.
  add_compile_options(/permissive-)
endif()

# enable shared libraries (aka. DLLs)
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build using shared libraries" ON)

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

# build the library
add_library(BigClass
  BigClass.cc BigClass.h)
set_target_properties(BigClass
  PROPERTIES
    PROJECT_LABEL "Big Class DLL"
    DEFINE_SYMBOL BUILD_BIG_CLASS)
if (NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  target_compile_definitions(BigClass PUBLIC BIG_CLASS_STATIC)
endif()

# build the tests
add_executable(Test1 Test1.cc)
target_link_libraries(Test1 BigClass)

add_executable(Test2 Test2.cc)
target_link_libraries(Test2 BigClass)
```

There are some specific things concerning the dynamic linking:

1. `option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build using shared libraries" ON)`
   This is explained in [CMake: Step 9: Selecting Static or Shared Libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Selecting%20Static%20or%20Shared%20Libraries.html).
2. `set_target_properties(BigClass PROPERTIES DEFINE_SYMBOL BUILD_BIG_CLASS)`
   This ensures that macro `BUILD_BIG_CLASS` will exclusively be defined in the command line of the compiler when the library `BigClass` is built.
3. ```
   if (NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
     target_compile_definitions(BigClass PUBLIC BIG_CLASS_STATIC)
   endif()
   ```

   The macro `BIG_CLASS_STATIC` will be defined in every compiler command line where the library `BigClass` is built or used.

*Disclaimer:* I'm aware of that one `CMakeLists.txt` for multiple projects is considered as bad style. For a serious project, libraries should reside in their own directory with their own `CMakeLists.txt` file, of course. I put it altogether to keep it as minimal as possible (and also because I can).

---

How it looks in Visual Studio 2019:

[image: Snapshot of VS 2019]

The build artefacts of Visual Studio 2019:

[image: Snapshot of Build binary dir]

Running `Test1.exe`:

```
Test1:
======
BigClass big;
big.print();
BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 0 }
big.printLn();
BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 0 }
BigClass big1(1);
big1.print();
BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 1 }
big1.printLn();
BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 1 }
Done.
```

Running `Test2.exe`:

```
Test2:
======
BigClass big;
print(big);
print(): BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 0 }
printLn(big);
BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 0 }
BigClass big2(2);
print(big2);
print(): BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 2 }
printLn(big2);
BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 2 }
Done.
```

---

Finally (to address the portability), I built the same CMake project in Linux:

```
Scheff'sCat@debian:/mnt/hgfs/hostD/Entwicklung/tests/C++/dll$ mkdir build-Linux
Scheff'sCat@debian:/mnt/hgfs/hostD/Entwicklung/tests/C++/dll$ cd build-Linux
Scheff'sCat@debian:/mnt/hgfs/hostD/Entwicklung/tests/C++/dll/build-Linux$ ccmake ..


Scheff'sCat@debian:/mnt/hgfs/hostD/Entwicklung/tests/C++/dll/build-Linux$ cmake --build .
Scanning dependencies of target BigClass
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/BigClass.dir/BigClass.cc.o
[ 33%] Linking CXX shared library libBigClass.so
[ 33%] Built target BigClass
Scanning dependencies of target Test2
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test2.dir/Test2.cc.o
[ 66%] Linking CXX executable Test2
[ 66%] Built target Test2
Scanning dependencies of target Test1
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test1.dir/Test1.cc.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Test1
[100%] Built target Test1
Scheff'sCat@debian:/mnt/hgfs/hostD/Entwicklung/tests/C++/dll/build-Linux$ ls
CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  libBigClass.so  Makefile  Test1  Test2
Scheff'sCat@debian:/mnt/hgfs/hostD/Entwicklung/tests/C++/dll/build-Linux$ ./Test1
Test1:
======
BigClass big;
big.print();
BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 0 }
big.printLn();
BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 0 }
BigClass big1(1);
big1.print();
BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 1 }
big1.printLn();
BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 1 }
Done.
Scheff'sCat@debian:/mnt/hgfs/hostD/Entwicklung/tests/C++/dll/build-Linux$ ./Test2
Test2:
======
BigClass big;
print(big);
print(): BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 0 }
printLn(big);
BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 0 }
BigClass big2(2);
print(big2);
print(): BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 2 }
printLn(big2);
BigClass::print(): *this: BigClass { id: 2 }
Done.
Scheff'sCat@debian:/mnt/hgfs/hostD/Entwicklung/tests/C++/dll/build-Linux$
```

Comment: Wow! This is very informative, thank you. It looks like I can't solve my problem without modifying BigClass to include the export functionality, but probably that is a good thing to do anyway.