# What does this class declaration format mean?

Tags: c++, class

I can analyzing a piece of code which is as follows:

```
class DPD_API gain_phase_calibrate : virtual public gr::block
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<gain_phase_calibrate> sptr;

    static sptr make();
};
```

From this code, I understand that a class called DPD_API is being created and it is inheriting from the gr::block class. What I dont understand is the gain_phase_calibrate. Is this a function name or a class name? Can anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: It can not be answered for sure, without more information, but it is very likely that gain_phase_calibrate is the class name and DPD_API is some macro.

Comment: `DPD_API` is probably a *macro* to make the class exported (or imported) from a DLL.

Comment: Thanks for the information. That is probably the case. I found this line in another part of the code. #define DPD_API __GR_ATTR_EXPORT

Comment: I would guess `DPD_API` is very much used as in this question [Macro for dllexport/dllimport switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980649/macro-for-dllexport-dllimport-switch).

Comment: Now my next question would be that why are macros used for the class definition. What do they assist with? Can anyone point me to an article explaining this?

Comment: @MobiZaman It's to do with exporting items from a DLL (or conversely importing items from a DLL). No doubt you can find a full explanation on the Microsoft site.

Comment: @MobiZaman Here you go, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/dllexport-dllimport?view=msvc-170

Comment: If you keep looking for where `__GR_ATTR_EXPORT ` is  defined, you will find that it expands to some platform-specific attributes. Then read about what those mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code snippet declares an API class called `gain_phase_calibrate` which inherits from `gr::block`. Here, `DPD_API` is the class' optional attributes, see [class declaration on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class).

The `DPD_API` macro will expand to platform and compiler specific code which controls the *visibility* of the class, i.e. whether it can be called from outside of the library.

In plain English, this code says "here's a class called `gain_phase_calibrate` and you can call it from your code if you use this library."

These macros are a common sight in C++ libraries. Conventionally, they are called `FOO_EXPORT` or `FOO_API` (as in this case).

Historically, shared objects on *NIX made all symbols visible while Microsoft's DLLs exposed only those with the `__declspec(dllexport)` macro. In the mean time, selectively exposing API symbols also caught on on *NIX.

A good summary for GCC (and comparison with the situation on Windows) can be found here in the [GCC wiki on Visibiliy](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility). It also features some sample code not unlike the one in the question.