# Why can't CMake find the dynamically linked lib file in the Windows environment?

Tags: c++

[image]

examples/CMakeLists.txt

```
#include "../include/thread_pool.h"

add_executable(pool_example pool_example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pool_example PRIVATE thread_pool)
```

examples/pool_example.cpp

```
#include "../include/thread_pool.h"

int main()
{
    fx::PoolTest();
    return 0;
}
```

include/thread_pool.h

```
#pragma once


namespace fx
{
    int PoolTest();
}
```

src/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(MODULE_NAME "thread_pool")
set(THREADPOOL_SRC
        thread_pool.cpp
)

add_library(${MODULE_NAME} SHARED ${THREADPOOL_SRC})
#add_library(${MODULE_NAME} STATIC ${THREADPOOL_SRC})
target_link_libraries(${MODULE_NAME})


target_include_directories(${MODULE_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

src/thread_pool.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../include/thread_pool.h"

namespace fx
{
    int PoolTest()
    {
        std::cout << "PoolTest" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

tests/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(TEST_SRC test.cpp
        ../include/thread_pool.h
)

add_executable(pool_test  ${TEST_SRC})
target_link_libraries(pool_test PUBLIC GTest::gtest GTest::gtest_main GTest::gmock GTest::gmock_main thread_pool)

add_test(NAME PoolTests COMMAND pool_test)
```

tests/test.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "../include/thread_pool.h"



TEST(BasicPoolTest, Test1)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(fx::PoolTest(), 1);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)  # 确定 CMake 最低版本要求
project(CppThreadPool
        VERSION 0.1.0
        DESCRIPTION "A simple thread pool for C++"
        LANGUAGES C CXX)  # 项目名称及使用的编程语言

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)  # 设置 C++ 标准



# 编译选项
option(BUILD_POOL_TEST "Build pool test" ON)
option(BUILD_POOL_EXAMPLES "Build pool examples" ON)



# 添加子目录
add_subdirectory(src)

if (BUILD_POOL_EXAMPLES)
    add_subdirectory(examples)
endif ()

if (BUILD_POOL_TEST)
    enable_testing()
    find_package(GTest CONFIG REQUIRED)
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif ()
```

The above is the entire contents of my project, but there will be an error：
[image]

[image]

```
[1/4] Building CXX object examples\CMakeFiles\pool_example.dir\pool_example.cpp.obj
[2/4] Building CXX object src\CMakeFiles\thread_pool.dir\thread_pool.cpp.obj
[3/4] Linking CXX shared library src\thread_pool.dll
[4/4] Linking CXX executable examples\pool_example.exe
FAILED: examples/pool_example.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && "D:\JetbrainAPP\CLion Nova\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=examples\CMakeFiles\pool_example.dir --rc=D:\WINDOW~1\10\bin\100226~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=D:\WINDOW~1\10\bin\100226~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- D:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\2022\ENTERP~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1436~1.325\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo examples\CMakeFiles\pool_example.dir\pool_example.cpp.obj  /out:examples\pool_example.exe /implib:examples\pool_example.lib /pdb:examples\pool_example.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  src\thread_pool.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cmd.exe /C "cd /D D:\AAAMyCode\Clion\CppThreadPool\cmake-build-debug\examples && C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file D:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1 -targetBinary D:/AAAMyCode/Clion/CppThreadPool/cmake-build-debug/examples/pool_example.exe -installedDir D:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/bin -OutVariable out""
LINK Pass 1: command "D:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\2022\ENTERP~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1436~1.325\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo examples\CMakeFiles\pool_example.dir\pool_example.cpp.obj /out:examples\pool_example.exe /implib:examples\pool_example.lib /pdb:examples\pool_example.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console src\thread_pool.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:examples\CMakeFiles\pool_example.dir/intermediate.manifest examples\CMakeFiles\pool_example.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: 无法打开文件“src\thread_pool.lib”
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

How can I generate a lib file? The error disappears when I change it to static linking, but I don't want to make the change and still want to use dynamic linking.

thank soooooo much

The error disappears when I change it to static linking, but I don't want to make the change and still want to use dynamic linking.

If my understanding is completely wrong, please tell me how to modify it. Thank you very much.

Comment: What does `无法打开文件` mean?

Comment: I expect that the problem is in your header file. For the import library to be created you need to export symbols from the dll using `__declspec(dllexport)`. If no symbols are exported the import library is not created at all. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980649/macro-for-dllexport-dllimport-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980649/macro-for-dllexport-dllimport-switch)

Comment: BTW, I have a full library example code on github that I have tested in Windows and linux: [https://github.com/drescherjm/CMakeLibraryExample](https://github.com/drescherjm/CMakeLibraryExample)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't want to export the DLL. My problem is that the dynamic linking can't find the lib file.

Comment: Again if you don't export symbols from the DLL the the .lib is not created so you can't link to the import library. And even if it were created it would be empty so you couldn't use the functionality of the dll.

Comment: You may want to understand how dlls work in windows first using this Microsoft example: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170)