# Where does <LIBNAME>_EXPORTS comes from?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, cmake

I have seen many c++ header file under MSVC environment like this:

```
#ifdef somelib_EXPORTS
#define DLLEXPORTS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLEXPORTS __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Where does the `<libname>_EXPORTS` convention come from ?

Is it a Visual Studio's default macro ? Or is it generated by CMake ?

I can't find any document about this convention.

Comment: It is probably generated by the default project template included with Visual Studio. But it's just convention—it has no other meaning. You can use any name you want. See more generally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863193/what-does-declspecdllimport-really-mean

Comment: Nothing to do with CMake, this convention has been in use well before that even existed.

Comment: `CMake` documentation says that the default macro from `CMake` is `LIBNAME_EXPORT` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/GenerateExportHeader.html however it's easy to change the default or the library may generate a similar header without using GenerateExportHeader.

Comment: if you are using vc i.e. VisualStudio, you may see it is defined in the `preprocessor definitions`, which is in `project property -> config property -> c/c++ -> preprocessor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where does the _EXPORTS convention come from ?

This is general coding guideline that helps with making sure that a .h file can be `#include`d while building a DLL and by the users of the DLL.

The name `DLLEXPORTS` is project specific. It can be generated by CMake, qmake, or manually. I don't think Visual Studio can generate them, at least I haven't seen that.

If you have 10 DLLs in your project, you will end up using 10 such macros. For example, you might have `UTILITY_DLL_EXPORT`, `MESSAGING_DLL_EXPORT`, `KERNEL_DLL_EXPORT`, etc.