# Using dllimport in place of dllexport

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport, declspec

I seem to be able to use `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` interchangeably when building my dll in Visual Studio 2015. I would have thought when making the DLL that the `dllexport` command would have been required but it seems either `dllexport` or `dllimport` is adequate.I have the following header file declaring a simple add() functions:

add.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef ADDDLL_EXPORTS
#define ADDDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ADDDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

ADDDLL_API int add(int x, int y);
```

with the following definition in a cpp file:

add.cpp

```
#include "add.h"

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

I seem to be able to use the built DLL whether `ADDDLL_EXPORTS` is defined or not in Configuration Properties > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions. For example, in a separate project which includes the .lib file as an additional dependency (Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies), I have the following code that runs

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"

int main()
{
    int sum = add(4, 5);
    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << std::endl;
    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Any insight appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does \_\_declspec(dllimport) really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863193/what-does-declspecdllimport-really-mean)

Comment: Thanks, I don't think this is a duplicate of the above post. I (believe) I understand what `dllimport` and `dllexport` are used for, but I'm not sure why I seem to be able to use them interchangeably because (I believe) they have opposite functions.

Comment: You are able to *build* your DLL alright, are you able to *use* it?

Comment: @n.m., yes, I able to use it. I'll update my post to clarify this.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @CristiFati, sorry if it wasn't clear. The questions was why I can use `dllimport` in place of `dllexport`. n.m. was able to answer my question below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look carefully, you will see that your DLL project compiles with *warnings*, like this:

```
 c:\yourproject\add.cpp(3,1):warning C4273: 'add': inconsistent dll linkage
```

The compiler knows that you are up to no good. A `dllimport` function should not be defined, only declared. So when the compiler sees the definition, it assumes `dllexport` should be used instead, because that's the most reasonable resolution of the mistake.

It is a good practice to [treat compiler warnings as errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).

Comment: You're right! Guess I need to learn to pay more attention to the output window haha. How do you know the compiler replaces `dllimport` with `dllexport`? Thanks!