# What is the need for dllimport?

Tags: visual-c++, dllimport, declspec

I am playing with DLLs to get a better understanding of them. So I created a simple dll (with load-time dynamic linking) which has functions to `Add`, `Sub` and `Mul`. In the header file for the dll I used `__declspec(dllexport)` for the function declaration.

For the executable, I added the .lib created after compiling the dll to the properties (for linking). After that I directly called the function `Add` without using `__declspec(dllimport)`. The program worked. I then changed the function calling to `__declspec(dllimport) (Add)` and the program worked again.

I am not able to understand what the need of `__declspec(dllimport)` is? I have not yet coded a run-time linking DLL but from the examples I have seen, dllimport is not needed in that case as well.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg for editing the code part, will take care in future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why/when is __declspec( dllimport ) not needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489441/why-when-is-declspec-dllimport-not-needed)

Comment: @HansPassant yes this is, I could not find the answer earlier. Apologies. Thanks for the pointer