# What is a 'thunk'? (in the context of re-entrant sort functions, eg: qsort_r)

Tags: c, naming-conventions

Having already checked [What is a 'thunk'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641489/what-is-a-thunk), I'm still not sure why the extra argument passed to the re-entrant `qsort_r` would be called `thunk`.

Eg: (BSD style `qsort_r`)

```
void qsort_r(void *base_, size_t nmemb, size_t size, void *thunk,
             int (*compar)(void *, const void *, const void *));
```

---

To be clear, I know what the argument is for, and how to use it, just not why its called `thunk` (in the BSD's `qsort_r` at least).

Comment: Yeah, I always wonder why it is not just called "Fred". Just kidding. I checked for a translation, but did not find a good answer why they actually choose that name. I'd say just accept and do not think about it:-)

Comment: @Olaf, I mainly asked because was writing my own sorting function and went to add `thunk` arg... when writing own API's I like to know reasons behind naming.

Comment: I like that attitude! That information was missing actually. However, you can choose the name freely as you know. Just call it "current_state" or so. I think "thunk" might just sound crispier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name seems to be from the [original proposed implementation](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-arch/2007-March/006126.html) by [Diomidis Spinellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20520/diomidis-spinellis)

The [implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-997.90.3/stdlib/FreeBSD/qsort.c) shows that it is just used as an opaque data block, passed through `qsort_r` and back to your compare function.

It seems to somewhat match the 3rd concept in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641492/10396).

> a mapping of machine data from one system-specific form to another, usually for compatibility reasons

But really, it just seems like a misleading name.  I usually think of thunks as containing blocks of code.  In this case it is just a container for context.

Comment: If I recall decissions I made years ago, I would not rely on that :-) Never mind.