# How to use WINAPI function (that isn´t Callback) inside a class?

Tags: c++, class, winapi, methods

I want to create a class that uses the WINAPI AddVectoredExceptionHandler.

I googled a bit and everybody says to make it static since the WINAPI is purely C and doesnt know classes.

If I make it static I am not able to use a class member inside the static function.

After that I googled a bit on "how to call non-static method from static method of same class? c++"

But didnt found anything but for Callback WINAPI functions.

https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/655/How-to-provide-a-CALLBACK-function-into-a-C-class-object.html

How can I use this WINAPI in a class? since it isnt a Callback function? (I also googled Callback function) (Doesnt seem to be one?)

```
class VEH
{
 public:
    VEH();
private: 
    void functionA(int a);
    /*static*/ LONG ExceptionHandler(EXCEPTION_POINTERS* ExceptionInfo);

};




VEH::VEH()
{
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(2,(PVECTORED_EXCEPTION_HANDLER)ExceptionHandler); //INVALID TYPE CONVERSION (if non static)
}


void functionA(int a){

}  


LONG ExceptionHandler(EXCEPTION_POINTERS* ExceptionInfo){
functionA(2); //a non-static member reference must be relative to a specific object (if static)
}
```

Comment: the `VectoredHandler` is global by sense function. it not receive additional context in call.so you can not got here pointer to instance of class (if this is not global instance). of course possible dynamic allocate executable memory thunk, which call your class member function, but really no sense do this. anyway - are you plan have *multiple* instance of class `VEH` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Remy Lebeau for providing an Answer to SergeyA who answers my questions but didnt provide a method to do it.

One "hackish" way would be to use a thunk for the actual VEH callback, and then store the class object pointer inside of that thunk. The thunk can then call methods on the class object as needed when itself is called by a vectored exception being raised. – Remy Lebeau 13 hours ago

After googling what a "thunk" is

[What is a 'thunk'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641489/what-is-a-thunk)

I just followed his comment.

Answer (score 2):

You are out of luck (almost). Since `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` doesn't seem to be able to store any context beyond the handle, there is no legal C++ way to call a non-static member function from it. (There is a hackish way, but I see no reason to recommend it now). Remember, calling a non-static member function requires to provide a instance of the class as well, and there is simply nowhere you can put this instance.

However, the function `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` is global. It should not be specific to any specific class instance, and because of that it makes no sense to have a per-object flavor of it. Once the exception happens, it happens - and it is not related to any particular class or object in your program. So `static` class member function or even global function should be enough for you.

Bottom line: you can't, and you most likely do not need to.

Comment: One "hackish" way would be to use a **thunk** for the actual VEH callback, and then store the class object pointer inside of that thunk.  The thunk can then call methods on the class object as needed when itself is called by a vectored exception being raised.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes, it is the hackish way I was mentioning, but I am more than certain OP doesn't need it.