# Xcode Instruments, Leaks. Meaning of "thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranted() -> ()"

Tags: xcode, syntax, memory-leaks, instruments, xcode-instruments

I often see this line in the Stack Trance when trying to track a memory leak in Xcode Instruments:

```
thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> ()
```

What does it mean? I can't even translate *thunk* word, not to mention its technical meaning in this context. The full stack trace looks like this:

```
0 libsystem_malloc.dylib calloc
1 libobjc.A.dylib weak_resize(weak_table_t*, unsigned long)
2 libobjc.A.dylib weak_register_no_lock
3 libobjc.A.dylib objc_storeWeak
4 SpriteKit -[SKNode(setParent) setParent:]
5 SpriteKit -[SKNode insertChild:atIndex:]
6 SpriteKit -[SKNode addChild:]
7 IOSTest PieceNode.setup() /.../PieceNode.swift:66
8 IOSTest LabeledPieceNode.setup() /.../PieceNode.swift:86
9 IOSTest closure #1 in closure #1 in MaskedRectBoardNodeController.maskedRectBoard(_:didFill:with:alongGravity:) /.../MaskedRectBoardNodeController.swift:48
10 IOSTest thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () /.../<compiler-generated>:0
11 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_call_block_and_release
12 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_client_callout
13 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp
14 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
15 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
16 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
17 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal
18 UIKitCore UIApplicationMain
19 IOSTest main /.../PauseMediator.swift:13
20 libdyld.dylib start
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A thunk generally is a box around a delayed function call (possibly adding some context, and possibly requiring additional context to complete). In Swift, thunks are generally used to help manage memory or calling conventions around a closure. As a rule, you can ignore the thunk; it's a bit of an implementation detail.

What this is really telling you is that you're leaking an SKNode somewhere, and that SKNode was created in a block dispatched to the main queue (probably using `DispatchQueue.main.async`). It is highly unlikely that this call stack actually has anything to do with the leak. It's just telling you where the leaked object was created.

Comment: Thanks! The topic of this particular leak is mysterious and lies outside of this question.

Comment: So if we imagine that a closure is a structure, then it will contain a `thunk` and `functionPointer`, right?

Comment: The thunk generally would *be* that structure. A closure is often implemented as a thunk, but it doesn't have to be. For example, if a closure is executed immediately, we may be able to avoid creating a thunk at all. This discussion from C++ has some nice explanations of one way that thunks can be implemented (but you should take this discussion as illustrative from one language, not a definition): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641489/what-is-a-thunk

Comment: Thunks are very common in lazily-evaluated functional languages. If I have some function that returns a lazy sequence, it might return `[(thunk)]`. If I evaluate the first element, it might be replaced with `[firstElement, (thunk)]`, etc. The point of the thunk is to hold a computation (including all the context required for that computation) that may be required later.

Comment: First time I've heard about a "thunk" in this context, despite my user name. Thanks to @RobNapier for the simple explanation.