# (go) Deep equality for ssh.AuthMethod

Tags: unit-testing, go

I'm using [crypto/ssh](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh) package and I'm trying to write a unit test for a method that constructs the ClientConfig.

One of the assertions in the unit is that the returned `ClientConfig` is deeply equal to the expected.
The assertion fails because both `Auth` and `HostKeyCallback` fields of `ClientConfig` are not deeply equal.
The `HostKeyCallback` is hardcoded to be `ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey()`.
The only authentication method I'm testing right now is with password and I have verified that the password string is picked up correctly.

I tried to mess around in playground (see [here](https://go.dev/play/p/WoyIDLf_ZOH)) and I don't understand why there is no deep equality in these cases.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {
    pass := "bar"
    auth := []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password(pass)}
    authLiteral := []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password("bar")}
    if reflect.DeepEqual(authLiteral, auth) {
        fmt.Println("authentication methods are equal")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("authentication methods are not equal")
    }

    callback1 := ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey()
    callback2 := ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey()
    if reflect.DeepEqual(callback1, callback2) {
        fmt.Println("callbacks are equal")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("callbacks are not equal")
    }
}
```

```
authentication methods are not equal
callbacks are not equal
```

Could someone please explain these results?
I would also be grateful if you could suggest how I could unit test this case.

Comment: Non-nil functions in Go are not comparable. No matter how "deep" you go. [`reflect.DeepEqual`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.18#DeepEqual): *"Func values are deeply equal if both are nil; otherwise they are not deeply equal."*

Comment: @mkopriva thanks a lot for pointing this out, I missed this part.
I assume there is no way to make the assertion that I want in ClientConfig then...

Comment: *One of the assertions in the unit is that the returned `ClientConfig` is deeply equal to the expected.* Why this check?

Comment: I have a method that generates the `ClientConfig` based on some configuration values (e.g. the username and password could come from a yaml file or from env variable etc) so there are multiple paths to test.
The method returns `*ClientConfig, error` so I though about checking that the returned values are the expected ones.

Am I off of the idiomatic go unit-testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mkopriva notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71716551/go-deep-equality-for-ssh-authmethod#comment126742149_71716551), this is formally disallowed.  (Still, it might be nice if [`reflect.DeepEqual`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.18#DeepEqual), which comes with the Go implementation, did something like I did below.  Because it comes with the implementation, the implementor can use special knowledge to write it.)

Ultimately, of course, there's some machine-level implementation for *pointer to function taking arguments of types T<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>2</sub>, ... T<sub>na</sub> and returning values value of types R<sub>1</sub>, R<sub>2</sub>, ... R<sub>nr</sub>* .  But we're not told *what* that representation *is*.  It might be a single `unsafe.Pointer` value, or it might be some kind of inline expansion of a [thunk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2641489/1256452).  So we don't know how many bytes to compare here.

If you're willing to make rather dangerous / non-portable assumptions, and update them if and when they prove inadequate, there *is* a way to "cheat" here.  I made [this example](https://go.dev/play/p/g9BmQohrIYL) on the Go Playground, which produces the desired output.  Is this just by chance, or does this really work on *your* Go implementation?

The text is also below.  Use at your own risk!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func dummy1() {}
func dummy2() {}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("dummy1 == dummy2 =>", qe(dummy1, dummy2))
    fmt.Println("dummy1 == dummy1 =>", qe(dummy1, dummy1))
}

// "questionably equal", for function pointers
func qe(a, b func()) bool {
    pp1 := (*unsafe.Pointer)(unsafe.Pointer(&a))
    pp2 := (*unsafe.Pointer)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
    p1 := *pp1
    p2 := *pp2
    return p1 == p2
}
```