# C++ Memory Layout: Questions about multiple inheritance, virtual destructors, and virtual function tables

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, memory-layout, virtual-destructor, virtual-table

I have a `main.cpp` file as follows.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

class Base1
{
public:
    int ibase1;
    Base1() : ibase1(10) {}
    virtual void f_b1_1() { printf("Base1::f_b1_1()()\n"); }
    virtual void f_b1_2() { printf("Base1::f_b1_2()()\n"); }
    virtual ~Base1() { printf("Base1::~Base1()\n"); }
};
class Base2
{
public:
    int ibase2;
    Base2() : ibase2(20) {}
    virtual void f_b2_1() { printf("Base2::f_b2_1()()\n"); }
    virtual void f_b2_2() { printf("Base2::f_b1_2()()\n"); }
    virtual ~Base2() { printf("Base2::~Base2()\n"); }
};
class Base3
{
public:
    int ibase3;
    Base3() : ibase3(30) {}
    virtual void f_b3_1() { printf("Base3::f_b3_1()\n"); }
    virtual void f_b3_2() { printf("Base3::f_b3_2()\n"); }
    virtual ~Base3() { printf("Base3::~Base3()\n"); }
};
class Derive : public Base1, public Base2, public Base3
{
public:
    int iderive;
    Derive() : iderive(100) {}
    virtual void f_b1_1() { printf("Derive::f_b1_1()\n"); }
    virtual void f_b2_1() { printf("Derive::f_b2_1()\n"); }
    virtual void f_b3_1() { printf("Derive::f_b2_1()\n"); }
    virtual void f_d_1() { printf("Derive::f_d_1()\n"); }
    virtual ~Derive() { printf("Derive::~Derive()\n"); }
};

int main()
{
    Derive d;
    long **pVtab = (long **)&d;
    for (int i = -2; i <= 18; ++i)
    {
        printf("vtab offset=%d  addr=%lx\n", (i + 2) * 8, pVtab[0][i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I use the `g++ -fdump-lang-class -c main.cpp` command to view the memory layout of the object, which generates the `main.cpp.001l.class` file, the following is part of that file.
[image]

And the output of `main.cpp` is as follows.

[image]

My questions are:

1. What is the meaning of the content in the red box?
2. What is the relationship between `Derive::_ZThn16_N6Derive6f_b2_1Ev` and `Derive::f_b2_1`?
3. What is the relationship between `Derive::_ZThn16_N6Derive6f_b3_1Ev` and `Derive::f_b3_1`?
4. Are `Derive::_ZThn16_N6DeriveD1Ev`,  `Derive::_ZThn16_N6DeriveD0Ev`, `Derive::_ZThn32_N6DeriveD1Ev`, `Derive::_ZThn32_N6DeriveD0Ev` and `Derive::~Derive` related?
5. Does the above relate to "C++ trunk"?

The os is: Ubuntu 20.04

The g++ version is: 9.4.0

What materials should I read?

I look forward to your help and I would like to thank you in advance.

Comment: A few (unrelated) things: First of all please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question); Secondly, why are you using `printf` for output in your C++ program? Also, `long` isn't guaranteed to be 64 bits, and can therefore not be used to hold addresses. Just like all other type the actual size depends on multiple factors.

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, what's wrong with `printf`?

Comment: @Elliott Type-safety, as I mentioned. Take for the example the OP using the `%lx` format specifier to print a `long` value. The problem is that the `x` format implies an *unsigned* value, while `long` is a *signed* value. Mismatching format specifier and argument value type leads to *undefined behavior*. With `std::cout` and the overloaded `<<` operator there's no such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What is the meaning of the content in the red box?
> 2. Does the above relate to "C++ trunk"?

The symbols you highlighed are [*mangled*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), you can use some demangle tools, like [c++filt](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html)

```bash
> c++filt _ZThn16_N6Derive6f_b2_1Ev
non-virtual thunk to Derive::f_b2_1()
```

As to your rest questions, you could refer to [What is a 'thunk'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641489/what-is-a-thunk) this SO question and answers.

It's a part of ABI, you could refer to [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/)