# Ruby hash with lazy keys

Tags: ruby, hashmap, key, lazy-evaluation

I have a collection of 'data endpoints'. Each endpoint has a name and can be available or unavailable. In Ruby I want to present the available endpoints as a Hash to make it easy to work with them. The difficulty is that getting information about the endpoints is costly and should be done lazily.

Some examples of how I want my object to behave:

```
endpoints = get_endpoints.call        # No endpoint information is accessed yet
result = endpoints['name1']           # This should only query endpoint "name1"
is_available = endpoints.key? 'name2' # This should only query endpoint "name2"
all_available = endpoints.keys        # This has to query all endpoints
```

The comments describe how the object internally makes requests to the 'data endpoints'.

It is [straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431124/is-there-a-built-in-lazy-hash-in-ruby) to make a Hash that can do the first 2 lines. However I don't know how to support the last 2 lines. To do this I need a way to make the keys lazy, not just the values.

Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: Not sure what aspect of Hash you would like to be lazy-implemented ? Keys evaluation ? How would it be addressed in memory ?

Comment: Hi @MrAleister Yes, keys evaluation (or rather, all aspects of the map). I have no idea how it would be addressed in memory. I thought that didn't really matter since it's object oriented, the same way I can just provide a lazy evaluation block for the values I would hope to provide a lazy evaluation block for the keys.

Comment: What do you mean by  *"I have made the value lookup lazy in the straightforward way"*? Why is that *"no advantage in [your] scenario if [you] have to look up the keys eagerly"*?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. (Why do you want to do this?) Can you show what code you've written so far? You could just use `my_hash.keys.lazy`, but... *why*? What would be the purpose?

Comment: Hi @TomLord . It is not laziness on the output side of the hash that I want, but laziness on the input side of the hash. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @user183966 No, that doesn't really make sense to me. Can you please provide a [mcve] of the problem? At a guess, perhaps what you'd like to do is define each hash **value** as a **lambda** - and only evaluate this at the point of accessing? Or perhaps you're looking at this the wrong way, and what's really needed is some optimisation of how/when the "eager loading" is performed.

Comment: @user183966 not really, could you please present some example of such lazy-input ?

Comment: `by passing a block to the Hash, and an exception is thrown if that key is not associated with an available data source` so Hash with a query interface where query itself is in a form of code block ?

Comment: I have rewritten the question using code examples to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: You say, "..I want to present the available endpoints as a Hash..." What are the hash's keys ("endpoints"?) and values ("available")? What is the "expensive" operation? (Determining if an endpoint is "availIable"?) Do you simply want to avoid determining if an endpoint is available if you've previously made that determination (i.e., assuming it will remain in its earlier state). Meaningless jargon ("lazy keys") is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to override the `key?` method, and do your own checking in there.

```
class LazyHash < Hash
  def key?(key)
    # Do your checking here. However that looks for your application
  end
end
```

In my opinion, you're asking for trouble though. One of the most powerful virtues in computer science is expectability. If you're changing the behavior of something, modifying it far beyond it's intent, it doesn't serve you to continue calling it by the original name. You don't need to shoe-horn your solution into existing classes/interfaces.

Programming offers you plenty of flexibility, so you *can* do stuff like this (dependent on the language of course), but in that same argument, you have no reason not to simply build a new object/service with it's own API.

I recommend starting fresh with a new class and building out your desired interface and functionality.

```
class LazyEndpoints
  def on?(name)

  end

  def set(name, value)

  end
end
```

(Or something like that, the world is yours for the taking!)